# how to properly free dynamicaly allocated memory in class methods in c++

Tags: c++, class, memory

I'm trying to write a method to overload the * operator for multiplying matrices. the matrix it self has its data stored in a dynamically allocated array "_mat_arr" and after running a valgrind check i cant seem to free it properly after finishing with this method.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator* (const Matrix& rhs)
{
    Matrix new_mat(this->_rows,rhs._cols);
   /*...code to fill the product matrix...*/
    return new_mat;
}
```

this is my destructor

```
~Matrix() /*destructor*/
    {
        delete [] _mat_arr;
        _mat_arr = nullptr;
    }
```

this is my class constructor where i allocate the matrix array

```
Matrix(int rows, int cols):_rows(rows),_cols(cols)
    {
        _mat_arr = new int [cols*rows];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            _mat_arr[i] = 0;
        }
        _rowLen = _cols -1;
    }
```

edit: changed delete to delete[].
after running the debugger i think that the problem is that the destructor is not called on new_mat which is allocated inside the method.

Comment: You should also define copy constructor and copy assignment.

Comment: `delete _mat_arr;` should be `delete[] _mat_arr;`

Answer (score 0):

Your destructor does not use the correct `delete`. It should call the array version of `delete`, `delete []`.

You should also apply Rule of 3 here. Since you are allocating dynamic memory and defining a destructor, you should also define a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator.

```
Matrix(const Matrix& other);
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other);
```

Comment: the problem still persists even after changing to delete [ ] in fact nothing changed in the memory check as i still have one memory allocation not freed, also i  forgot to mention that i do have a copy constructor and an assignment operator

Comment: Sorry, your question got closed by an over-eager person with too much power. Can you request reopening this one so someone else can have a shot at it?